# TFS Build Controller : "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0"

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

As you know that your TFS Preivew does not support for Azure SDK 1.8 so We are using On-permises TFS build controller to build our project.

During Azure Continous Inegration deployment build we are getting this error

```
========================================
Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
========================================
```

We have updated Storage library to version 2.0 using nuget but still we are getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received this solution from TFS support.  THis isn't working since upgrading to TFS 2013 though.

To fix the assembly loading error, you need to copy

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\2012-06\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll"

To

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools

On the build machine and restart the service.

Comment: I had the same issue only with TFS 2013 and Azure.Storage.dll 2.0 and copying the files to the TFS\tools folder worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Detailed or Diagnostic Logging Verbosity to determine if `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` or one of it's dependents are missing. If you are able to compile locally, you could have the assembly installed in your local GAC but not on the build server.

[image: TFS Logging Verbosity]

Comment: this file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-10\ref and it is also exist on server

Comment: $/tfscloudtest/drops/tfscloudtest_CD/tfscloudtest_CD_20121205.3/_PublishedWebsites/WebRole1/bin     is also available in this folder

Comment: I removed all refrences of storage dlls but still same error i dont know from where it is refrenceign this dll

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't more clear. Did you review the detailed build log on tfs. Search the build log for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient`. It should indicate the paths it is checking to find the assembly.

Comment: That is issue it is not showing any path and big issue is project has no refrence to this library anymore now

Comment: If you don't have a project reference to the assembly, how do you expect the build to resolve the reference? Does the solution compile locally? If so, turn on Detailed Build Output (Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run/Build Output Verbosity) for local build and check the assembly resolution.

Comment: @zebra, what have you tried? what paths are listed for `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` in the detailed build output?

Comment: well for me it was not build problem for sure, I had this dll from the begining in lib directory, all of my projects were refencing it from lib, and all of them compiled. on my detailed log I get 60 warnings 0 errors,and all projects have the dll in bin directory. For me the issue was during deployment it was only after the build agent wanted to upload packages to azure where the problem would appear, azure deployment task (I guess) needed it. I solved the problem by putting dll in GAC, its not perfect but publishing works, do you know if there is etter solution than putting it to  GAC?