# Team Foundation Server Deployment error

Tags: django, azure, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I have setup my own Team Foundation Build server and I am using Visual Studio Online to host my project online. I have a django project which I am trying to deploy on windows azure cloud service. The project can be published from my dev machine without any errors however when the build server tries to build it, it gives the following error during uploading the package:

> Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type FileNotFoundException)

I checked in .pyproj and found a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage but there the version is 2.1.0.0 and that is the version that is installed on the server as well.

Also there are no errors during the build process but only during the deployment stage. How do I make Msbuild use Storage version 2.1.0.0 instead of 2.0.0.0 . Also, which SDK version contains Storage version 2.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. This is the same problem as [TFS Build Controller : "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710916/tfs-build-controller-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-windowsazure).

You'll need to copy Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll version 2.0.0.0 to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools", and then restart the Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host 2013 service.